# datediff() of 2 timestamps that contain decimal values

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I've been stumbling with this issue for a couple days now, and cannot seem to figure out why, when my getdate() insert into the columns are providing a millisecond decimal to the military time format, I still cannot seem to be able to pull a decimal format datediff() result. Does it have to do with the engine not recognizing the decimal due to the surrounding '' characters?

When I use:

```
select datediff(s,'2013-06-01 21:59:59.141','2013-06-01 23:59:59.997')
```

It returns:

```
7200
```

And when I use:

```
select cast(datediff(s,'2013-06-01 21:59:59.141','2013-06-01 23:59:59.997') as float);
```

It returns:

```
7200
```

I am at a loss as to what I am missing in order to result in a decimal value.

Thanks

Comment: The return type of `datediff` is an `int`. Even if you `cast` it to `float` you would get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that DATEDIFF(MS, ...) requires guarding for long time spans or it will give an overflow:

```
SELECT datediff(MS, '2013-06-30 23:59:59.997', '2013-06-01 21:59:59.141')
-- FAILURE: The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large
```

You can use following method which is overflow-safe and gives you a float result:

```
SELECT cast(cast('2013-06-01 23:59:59.997' as datetime)-cast('2013-06-01 21:59:59.141' as datetime) as float) * 24.0
-- Returned 2.00023796296296

SELECT cast(cast('2013-06-30 23:59:59.997' as datetime)-cast('2013-06-01 21:59:59.141' as datetime) as float) * 24.0
-- Returned 698.000237962963
```

I'm not sure how this method works when time zone changed during the measured date period.

Comment: Good call, ill explore that as well. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up not needing to cast as datetime because it is already in the datetime data type:

select round(cast(punch_out - punch_in as float) *24,4) as elapsed from punches;

punch_out and punch_in were already datetimes, so this worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to get the milliseconds of the difference, and you want to convert the units to seconds, you can try using something like the following:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MS,'2013-06-01 21:59:59.141','2013-06-01 23:59:59.997') / 1000.0
```

That'll produce: `7200.856000`.

Comment: Will calculations at that scale affect performance over a large set of data? What I had failed to mentionwas my end result will be hours, rounded to 4 digits, and I was concerned of performance if this syntax is implemented over a large dataset when pulling for reporting.

    select round(cast((datediff(ms,'2013-06-01 21:59:59.141','2013-06-01 23:59:59.997')/1000.00)/3600 as float),4);

Comment: Thanks, that works and now the above will return 2.0002 hours for me. I just didn't know if this was the optimal route to go performance wise. Also if I do not cast as float it will return 2.000200000000.